# Problems mapping xml / json lsits to select2

Tags: javascript, json, xml, rest, jquery-select2

I am providing data over REST to a custom HTML form with a SELECT 2 inside it. However I am not able to map the data from REST to the SELECT 2!

javascript for my select2:

```
$("#space-select").select2({
  width : '100%',
  ajax : {
    delay: 500,
    url : url,
    type : 'GET',
    contentType : 'json',
    processResults : function(data) {
      return {
    results : $.map(data.spaces, function(space) {
      return {
        id: space,
        text: space,
      };
    })
      };
    }               
  }
});
```

incoming xml:

```
<configuration>
 <spaces>
  <space>Space 1</space>
  <space>Space 2</space>
  <space>Space 3</space>
 </spaces>
</configuration>
```

I dont really understand why the data is not mapped correctly!

Comment: What type of element is this `#space-select`?

Comment: it is a Select2 (https://select2.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I found the wrong part in my Code:

i used:

```
contentType : 'json',
```

but you have to use:

```
dataType : 'json',
```